# Can I modify the heat transfer equation by including the volumetric heat capacity in the partial time derivative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

Consider a porous material in which the pores can be drained or filled with water gradually in time. Thus, the volumetric heat capacity changes with time. Can I write the heat transfer equation ($\dot{q}$ is a heat source due to a chemical reaction) in this form?
$$
\frac{\partial (\rho C T)}{\partial t}=\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T) + \dot{q}
$$
When the time derivative is expanded
$$
\rho C \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial (\rho C)}{\partial t}T=\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T) + \dot{q}
$$
the second term on the left hand side is supposed to acount for the loss/gain of heat contained in the pore water.

Comment: yes but do not forget that you have time varying boundary conditions.

Comment: Your equations are incorrect.  In the first equation, the $rho$ and C should be outside the derivative, and, in the second equation, the 2nd term on the rhs should not be present.

Comment: the differential of entralpy per unit volume should be $dH=\rho C dT$.

Comment: Since we considering a solid we may neglect the PV term and have H=E, i.e. the enthalpy is equal to the internal energy. If we neglect  the strain energy, the internal energy is the heat energy. The heat energy at T=0 K is zero. Integrating $dH=\rho C dT$  we get $H=\rho C T$. Having in mind that volumetric heat capacity is time dependent we may write  $dH=d(\rho C T)$.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: you cannot integrate it that way unless you assume that $\rho C$ is independent of $T$ and in your problem you have assumed the contrary. If you assume independence wrt $T$ then the 2nd partial wrt time is zero and this is how you end up with variable (moving) boundary condition between two "constant $\rho C$ domains" and at the "jump" you have to fit them smoothly together.

Comment: $\rho C$ does not depend on temperature T, it depends on time t.  There are no two domains. It is one domain, say concrete, with uniform porosity distribution and which, for simplicitly, can be uniformly drained or filled with water.

Comment: even if you assume that $\rho C$ is independent of $T$ but depends only  on $t$, @ChetMiller is still correct and you still have two diff eqs that you are to match through a common moving boundary.

Comment: C is a function of state, and, as such, it must depend on state parameters such as T and specific volume, not directly on t.

Comment: @ChetMiller you are right that ultimately it must also depend on $T$ but let us ignore *that* dependence as compared to what it will be when you are filling, say, a low density porous material with water; just take, engineering-wise, the approximate time dependence on $t$.

Comment: @hyportnex You are referring to an open system, correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller take a bucket of water and a bucket of dry sand as a start on which you pour the water, the two buckets taken together is a closed system but there is an internal matter flow. The buckets are diathermal. We can take $C_w, C_s$ nearly constant between, say, 32F and 180F

Comment: This is getting pretty far removed from the issue @kyle kanos and I were trying to resolve

Comment: @ChetMiller that may be but I think this is the scenario of the problem above, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The integral of $dH=\rho(T) C(T) dT$ is not $H=\rho C T$ if C is a function of T (which it often is).  The correct integral is $H=\int_{T_0}^T{\rho(T')C(T')dT}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question and at least one answer presuppose that the relevant energy $U$ per unit volume $V$, which we can term $u$, is the product of the density $\rho$, specific heat capacity $c$, and temperature $T$ and that temporal variation can occur in any of these parameters: $$u(t) = U(t)/V(t)=\rho(t) c(t)T(t).$$

**This is not correct.** As @Chet notes elsewhere, the specific heat capacity is defined by $c\equiv\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{du}{dT}$, not $c\equiv\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{u}{T}$.

Backing up a few steps, the [internal energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy#Internal_energy_of_multi-component_systems) of a system is $$U=TS-PV+\sum_i\mu_iN_i$$ with entropy $S$, pressure $P$, and chemical potential $\mu$ and amount $N$ of species $i$.

Now, if we consider a closed system and one speciies, the [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) is $$dU=T\,dS-P\,dV.$$

We could instead choose to work with variables $T$ and $V$; in a standard thermodynamics exercise (expanding $dU$ as $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$), we obtain $$dU=C\,dT+(\alpha TK-P)\,dV$$ with constant-volume heat capacity $C$, thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$, and bulk modulus $K$.

For a dynamic heat capacity $C(t)$ and approximately constant volume, the differential relation at any time $t$ is

$$dU=C(t)\,dT;$$

$$du=\rho c(t)\,dT.$$

To find the volumetric energy density as a function of time, following Minakov and Shick in "[Non-equilibrium fast thermal response of polymers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040603117303301)," we integrate through the history:

$$u(t)=\int_0^\infty \rho c(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(t-\tau)\,d\tau+u_0,$$

where $u_0$ is a reference energy density (e.g., before the temperature and heat capacity began to change).

Considering that the energy per unit volume is increased by Fourier conduction from the surroundings and by heat generation $\dot q$ (as specified in the question), the heat equation incorporating a dynamic heat capacity is then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^\infty \rho c(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(t-\tau)\,d\tau=\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)+\dot q.$$

However, your system isn't closed, and at least two species exist. So we perhaps have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); the issue isn't simply a dynamic heat capacity. Consider clarifying—with a new question—what you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Actually, if $du=\rho c dT$, then u=$\int_{T_0}^T{\rho c(T')dT'}$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\rho c(T)\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$

Answer (score 0):

The heat equation is derived from the conservation of energy, which states that the (partial) time derivative of the heat energy equals the spatial-derivative of the heat flux plus sinks/sources:
$$\frac{\partial e(x,t)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial\phi(x,t)}{\partial x}+Q(x,t).$$

Since the heat energy in the above is also equal to the product of the temperature, specific heat and density,
$$e(x,t)= c(x,t)\rho(x,t) T(x,t)$$
Then you are correct in saying that,
$$\frac{\partial e}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial(c\rho T)}{\partial t}\equiv c\rho\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+cT\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\rho T\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}$$
However, you may want to ensure that your heat flux, $\phi$, and boundary conditions are correctly specified in your scenario.

Comment: This is not correct.  See my comment above.

Comment: This is a straight-forward derivation from conservation of energy, so I'm not sure what part you find disagreeable. Other sources you can find online say the same thing, so I find it bizarre that you'd find something disagree with...

Comment: I stand by what I said.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al.

Comment: How would this be explained. Let the heat equation be simplified - no heat gradients and no source/sink.
$$
\rho C \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=0
$$
$\rho C$ could be cancelled and $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=0$ means that temperature remains constant.
However, from energy conservation point, if $\rho C$ increases twice for a certain time period, the temperature should decrease twice so that $\rho C T$ remains constant. There is a contradiction. For the cause of change of  $\rho C$ in time consider some aging which does not produce or consume heat

Comment: @Chet Seeing how I don't own that book, I cannot fathom your point. If you're going to be lazy and not provide an actual response (to OP), feel free to move on with your life.

Comment: @RTT65 if $T=\text{const}$ then you'd be balanced by $C\partial_t\rho=\rho\partial_tC$. If either of $\rho$, $C$ is time-independent, then the other must be also.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get a copy of Transport Phenomena.  You won't regret it.

Comment: @ChetMiller I work in finance; there is zero need for me to get that book.

Comment: If you work in finance,  maybe you should’nt be giving heat transfer advice to heat transfer experts like myself.

Comment: @ChetMiller LMAO, that's a good one. I've got a PhD in physics just like a bunch of other people on this site. The fact that I use my degree differently than others does not mean I shouldn't provide correct answers to any question. See, the first hit on search engine for `derivation of heat transfer partial differential equation` yields [this source](https://jmahaffy.sdsu.edu/courses/s17/math531/beamer/heat.pdf) (PDF) which shows largely the above.

Comment: Your reference is in error.  The "eat capacity of a material is not defined as the internal energy ('thermal energy density") divided b the temperature.  It is equal to the partial derivative of the internal energy with respect to temperature  It is incorrect to write the ""thermal energy density" in a form involving the product of heat capacity and temperature.

Comment: @ChetMiller. The textbooks do not discuss the contradiction mentioned above. If you can resolve and explain it, I'll be much obliged.

Comment: In all thermodynamics books (see e.g. Smith and van Ness or Denbigh), heat capacity at constant volume is defined as the partial derivative of internal energy with respect to temperature, not internal energy divided by temperature.

Comment: I agree that what you say is written in the textbooks. What I want is to resolve the contradiction  mentioned in my comments above. The only way I can do it is by starting with $\frac{\partial (\rho C T)}{\partial t}$.  After applying the chain rule I get the expected term $\rho C \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ plus another term $\frac{\partial (\rho C)}{\partial t}T$. This has the form of a source term and could describe the gain of heat when the volumetric heat capacity of a porous solid changes due to intake of water into the pores (for simplicity assume that it happens uniformly in space)

Comment: You are describing an open system, and should be starting with the open system form of the first law of thermodynamics.  What is the exact problem you are solving?

Comment: So you have $$\rho(T)C(T)\frac{\partial T}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(k(T)\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)+ G(T.t)$$Is this what you are trying to solve?

Comment: Not exactly. I am trying to solve this (for simplicity written for the case when it is spacially steady state, i.e. thermal gradient is zero) and the volumetric heat capacity is time dependent
$$
\rho(t)C(t)\frac{\partial T}{dt}= G(T.t)
$$

Comment: The basic problem is that in some case $G(T,t)$ is not obvious (say, the material ages and the  $\rho C$ changes. In other case (say, intake of water into the pores of the material) $G(T,t)$ has to be determined. If not determined correctly, the energy preservation could be violated. What I ask is if it can be calculated as $\frac{\partial (\rho C)}{\partial t}T$. The latter will ensure the correct energy balance based on the derivation of the term.

Comment: If the material ages, it means that a chemical reaction is occurring, and the heat of reaction effect as well as the effect of chemical makeup on the heat capacity has to be taken into account.  Can you provide more detail on this?  If you have a porous medium (or granular bed) and fluids are flowing through the bed, the equations have to include heat transfer between the fluid and the bed.  The formulation of the heat palaces on the fluid and bed are separate, and are connected by an interphase heat transfer coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is for @Kyle Kanos.  I'm going to derive the 1D version of the equation for a rod of constant cross sectional area.  So the internal energy per unit mass is given by $$\Delta u(T)=\int_{T_0}^T{C(T')dT'}$$ where $T_0$ is an arbitrary reference temperature and T' is a dummy variable of integration. So the total internal energy in the section of rod between $x-\Delta x/2$ and $x+\Delta x/2$ is given by $$U=\rho A\Delta x u=\rho A \Delta x \int_{T_0}^T{C(T')dT'}$$where A is the cross sectional area.

From the first law of thermodynamics, it follows that $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=q(x-\Delta x/2)A-q(x-\Delta x/2)A$$ where q is the axis heat flux.  If we combine the previous two equations, divide by A$\Delta x$, and take the limit as $\Delta x$ approaches zero, we obtain:$$\rho C\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$$

Comment: From the above equation, when the heat flux is zero, q=0,  it follows that T=const  whatever dependence $\rho C$ has. However, when there is no explicit heat source and the volumetric heat capacity  $\rho C$ is time dependent, say, it increase twice for time interval $\Delta t$ the temperature should decrease twice (from conservation of energy). 
How would you resolve this contradiction?

Comment: I don’t follow this at all.  Where does a factor of 2 come from?

Comment: It is just an example of a assumed change in the volumetric heat capacity for a given time interval given by a number rather than a variable or function.